# $P(A\vert \neg B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are dependent

Tags: probability, independence

I am used to seeing, for dependent events $A,B$, $$P(A \wedge B) = P(B)P(A\vert B) = P(B\vert A) P(A)$$

What if I want to condition on $B$ **not** happening. Then is it just
$$
P(A\wedge \neg B) = P(\neg B)P(A\vert \neg B)?
$$

Is there a relationship between $P(A\wedge B)$ and $P(A\wedge \neg B)$? Such as maybe $P(A\wedge B) + P(A\wedge \neg B) = P(A)$? If so, can a proof be provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$A = (A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B^c),$$
$$\Phi = (A \cap B) \cap (A\cap B^c),$$
and
$$\Pr(X \cup Y)  = \Pr(X) + \Pr(Y) - \Pr (X \cap Y). $$

Comment: so $P([A \wedge B] \cup [A\wedge \neg B]) = P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap \neg B) - P(\Phi) = P(A\vert B)P(B) + P(A\vert \neg B)P(\neg B)$ where $\Phi$ is the empty set. Thanks.